# How does instagram and vine iOS apps play videos inline?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

Without opening the fullscreen video player?

Are they using a webview? What is the format of the video?

Comment: I would assume they use AVPlayer, as you can customize it a lot more (size: you dont have to make it fullscreen, you can play 2 videos at once.. etc), and just get the video data from their servers.

Answer (score 3):

I inspected Instagram app using [Reveal](http://revealapp.com) and looks like they use an `AVPlayer`, which makes them able to customize it more than if they were using an `UIWebView` or `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Comment: How did you inspect 3rd party app with reveal?

Comment: I used a jailbroken device and followed [this post](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/how-to-inspect-the-view-hierarchy-of-3rd-party-apps/). I think there's a Cydia package now to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

use/try below code it's works i hoped.

```
NSString *embedHTML = @"\
  <html><head>\
  <style type=\"text/css\">\
  body {\
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  }\
  </style>\
  </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
  <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
  width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
  </body></html>";

  NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, yourURLString, width,height];//set width and height 

  [webView loadHTMLString:htmlStr baseURL:nil];
  [self.view addSubview:webView];
```

or

use try second approach via UIWebView class delegates method

[allowsInlineMediaPlayback](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW32)